# Date object doesn't exist after definition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I'm trying to make a function that returns an array of dates in between two dates. This is my code:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) 
        {
            var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
            return date;
        }


function getdaterange(startdate, enddate)
        {
            var s = new Date(startdate);
            var e = new Date(enddate);
            var datearray = [s];

            var done = false;
            while(!done)
            {
                var date = datearray.pop().addDays(1);
                if (date == e)
                {
                    datearray.push(date);
                    done = true;
                }                     
            }
        }

getdaterange("2018-09-01", "2018-09-25");
```

The function isn't done yet, but when I try to manipulate the date object on the line that sets the variable "date", it comes back as undefined or says that .pop() isn't a method of Date. I've tried several different configurations. (Where I change how I am manipulating the date object. For example: defining the variable and then calling the .addDays() method afterwards.)

This is just one of them. Does anybody know whats going on?

**Thanks for any help in advanced.**

**Thanks for your help from the comments. Edited Code:**

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) 
{
var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
return date;
} 

function getdaterange(startdate, enddate)
        {
            var s = new Date(startdate);
            var e = new Date(enddate);
            var datearray = [s];

            var done = false;
            while(!done)
            {
                var temp = datearray;
                var date = temp.pop().addDays(1);

                if (date.valueOf() == e.valueOf())
                {
                    datearray.push(date);
                    done = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    datearray.push(date);
                }      
            }
          return datearray;
        }
        console.log(getdaterange("2018-09-01", "2018-09-25"));
```

Comment: Your function only pushes a date onto the array if the date is equal to the end date, and that will never be the case because two distinct objects are never equal to each other. Thus the error happens on the second time through the loop, because the first time removed the only element from the array (via the call to `.pop()`).

Comment: `if (date == e)` and when that doesn't pass, you go in the next iteration of the loop but `dateArray` is empty and calling `.pop()` will return nothing.

Comment: You should compare **dates** with `date.valueof()`.

Comment: @vlaz That helped me, but now I've having problems with the function returning only one result in my array when I try to add to it. I think I'm using .push() wrong. I'll update my post with the new code so you can see what I;m talking about. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy and @Rahul!

Comment: @Rahul `valueOf`. Or `getTime`. @OP please don't modify built-in prototypes. In catch-22 fashion if you don't know that you shouldn't be doing it, you shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: You need to be a little careful: '2018-09-01' will be parsed as UTC, but you're using "local" methods to increment the date so it may appear shifted by 1 day depending on the host timezone offset.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for this input. Working on that problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to 'extend' the Date class, you can encapsulate the desired logic in it's own class as follows

```
class DateUtil {

    static addDays(date, days) {
        return date.setDate(date.getDate() + days)
    }

    static getDateRange(dateStart, dateEnd) {
        let date = new Date(dateStart);
        let endDate = new Date(dateEnd);
        let dates = [];
        while (date < endDate) {
            dates.push(new Date(this.addDays(date, 1)))
        }
        return dates;
    }
}

DateUtil.getDateRange('2018-09-01', '2018-09-25')
    .forEach(date => console.log(date.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up needing to do (after fixing the first problem) was set var temp equal to var datearray through a method like Array.from(). That way temp wasn't pointing to datearray directly and I always ended up with one item in the array.

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) 
        {
            var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
            return date;
        }

function getdaterange(startdate, enddate)
        {
            var s = new Date(startdate);
            var e = new Date(enddate);
            var datearray = [s];
            var done = false;

            while(!done)
            {
                var temp = Array.from(datearray);
                var date = temp.pop().addDays(1);

                if (date.valueOf() == e.valueOf())
                {
                    datearray.push(date);
                    done = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    datearray.push(date);
                }      
            }
          return datearray;
        }
```